# SSIS doesn't seem to fully support SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

The SSIS OData connection doesn't support multi-value choice fields. The older SharePoint list source from codeplex doesn't support O365 Authentication. Any suggestions on alternatives? Or is PowerShell the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

SSIS OData connection doesn't support multi-value choice field, you need to disable multiple values.